# close a popup modal and true the value on click event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create a popup window and put 2 button on that, and when click on the button the value of btn be true and close the popup and see the Main window,
I have done some thing! but when the main window loaded its gray!
I mean this:
[image]

and this:
[image]

and when press F12 in browser I see this:

```
<body class="modal-open" style=""></body>
```

and this is my .cshtml file:

```
@{
    List<string> formRows = new List<string>();

    string btnReceiptPrint = string.Format(@"<button id='BtnReceiptPrint' style='height:35px;width:110px;' class='btn btn-success' type='button' 
                    onclick='$(""#ReceiptPrint"").val(""true"");hideModal(this);_submitForm(""sellInvoiceForm"");'>{0}</button>", Resources.UI("ReceiptPrint"));

    string btnNormalPrint = string.Format(@"<button id='BtnNormalPrint' style='height:35px;width:110px;' class='btn btn-success' type='button' 
                    onclick='$(""#NormalPrint"").val(""true"");hideModal(this);_submitForm(""sellInvoiceForm"");'>{0}</button>", Resources.UI("NormalPrint"));

    formRows.Add("<p style ='text-align : center'>" + btnReceiptPrint + "</p>");
    formRows.Add("<p style ='text-align : center'>" + btnNormalPrint + "</p>");

    @Html.FormGroupGenerator(formRows)
}
```

Can anyone help me PLZ?

Answer (score 0):

When you press btn then do : `$('#your-modal').modal('hide')`. It will close the modal.